# Separate modules want to have different github origin. Spring-Angular

Tags: angular, spring, github, intellij-idea, module

I would like to make nice project structure with separated frontend module and backend module.
1 Project structure screen

[image]

I've done that before in multiple configurations, but every time git sees it like:

2 Project structure screen

[image]

Github remote config in the project

[image]

Or instead of Backend there is a Frontend module.
Long story short, can't make one repository with 2 modules where one is for frontend and one
and one is for backend.

Please help me, I've already wasted so much time..

I expect some thoughts or ideas how can I fix this issue with my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it in the following way:

- `File | Close Project | Close the IDE`
- Open your project in OS file explorer. Backup and delete all `.iml` files and the `.idea` directory
- Open the IDE and create a new empty project:
  [image: ![]()]
- Add your `Frontend` directory as module under `File | Project Structure | Modules | + | Import Module`. Apply and OK
- Repeat the previous step for `Backend` module